# Magento 2.4.5 after place order success page with customization

Tags: magento2, orders, third-party-library

Hello I have created one observer after the order is placed **(sales_model_service_quote_submit_success)** order data need to synch with some third-party system it is working fine order is synched to the system some time if any error from third-party system order success page not showing it redirecting to cart but order present in admin pannel I have placed any die like this code having any idea why it redirecting

```
try{
                     $response = $this->customhelper->doCall(str_replace('\"', ' ', json_encode($orderdata, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)));
                $resp = json_decode($response);
                $logger->info('ideal reposnse.=' . print_r($resp, true));
                if (isset($resp->Response) && $resp->Response == "Import Complete") {
                    $errorCount = $resp->ErrorCount;
                    $successCount = $resp->SuccessCount;
                    $logger->info('errosuccess counts===' . $errorCount . "==" . $successCount);
                    if ($errorCount >= 0 && $successCount >= 1) {

                        $resp = json_encode($response);
                        $order->setOrderSynch('Synched');
                        $order->save();
                        $logger->info('Status flag: ' . $order->getOrderSynch());
                    } else {
                        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                        $errorList = $resp->ErrorList;
//                        $errorList = json_encode($errorList);
                        $order->setOrderSynch('Synch Error- with error code ' . $errorList[0]->ErrorID);
                        $order->save();
                        $logger->info('Status flag : ' . $order->getOrderSync());
                    }
                } else {
                    $logger->info("Response we got from IDEAL." . print_r($resp, true));
                }
                } catch (Exception $ex) {
                     $logger->info('we got synch error.=' . print_r($ex->getMessage(), true));
                }
```

Comment: Please make the proper format of code... Complete code not showing in your question.

Comment: @NavneetSharma please check once updated my question